# "konsole -e" results in read-only terminal

Tags: linux, bash, konsole

I am trying to programmatically open a new terminal and automatically run a custom script that sets various environment variables to prime it for an interactive session. This all works fine, except the resulting terminal cannot be edited, i.e., there is no cursor.
My current attempt looks like this:

```
konsole -hold -e /path/to/bash/script/run_oenv.sh
```

where `run_oenv.sh` looks like this (for simple testing):

```
echo hello world
export FOO=bar
```

When running the above command `run_oenv.sh` is executed successfully and I see the expected debug statement echoed in the new terminal, but I just can't work out how to make the new terminal interactive.
What am I missing?

Ultimately the bash script will have to do more than just set environment variables but this is the simplest test case.

This is on Centos 7/KDE.

Comment: @mosvy I probably hit the spacebar by accident just before submitting the edit. Chill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `-e` with a terminal emulator to execute a command, it executes that command *instead* of the shell that it would have started.  This means that it runs your script and then nothing else.

If you want to start an interactive `bash` shell that sources your file, use `bash` with its `--rcfile` command line option:

```
konsole -hold -e bash --rcfile /path/to/bash/script/run_oenv.sh
```

Note that this makes `bash` *not* read the `~/.bashrc` file.  If you still want to source `~/.bashrc`, as would ordinary happen in interactive shell sessions, you would do so from your `run_oenv.sh` code:

```
[ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && source "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

or without the short-circuit syntax,

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    source "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
```

(probably at the top of the `run_oenv.sh` file to have your file override any variables or settings in `~/.bashrc`)

Comment: Thank you very much, I obviously misinterpreted the use of -e . One more complication I accidentally forgot to mention in an attempt to provide a simple example:
I actually need to pass a couple of arguments to my script like this:

    konsole -noclose -e bash --rcfile run_oenv.sh ARG1 ARG2

How do I incorporate that?

Comment: @FrankRueter You can't really pass command line arguments to an interactive shell. But there's something else you could try, and that's to go use something like `konsole -noclose -e run_oenv.sh ARG1 ARG2 ` where your script has a proper `#!`-line, and then, in the script, run `bash` at the end.

Comment: that makes sense. Thank you,it works now with your suggestion.